# Grep in List of Vectors (R)

Tags: r, list, vector

I tried to do vector of vectors in R. Found a proposition to do List of Vectors - now it works, but not fully correctly. When I try to grep sth in any vector from list I always receive "1". How do the vector of vectors, where I can grep in each?

```
waluty <- list(waluty96, waluty97, waluty98, waluty99, waluty00, waluty01, waluty02, waluty03, waluty04, waluty05, waluty06, waluty07, waluty08, waluty09, waluty10, waluty11, waluty12, waluty13, waluty14, waluty15, waluty16, waluty17)
grep("DEM", (waluty[2]))

[1] 1
```

Comment: probably use `lapply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply()`:

```
result <- lapply(waluty, function(x) grep("DEM", x))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Can't vote at your answer (not enough reputation), so lot of thanks to you!